# Is super heroes lighting their logos on fire a trope?

Tags: trope

Frank Castle did it in the first of the recent Punisher movies:

[image]

Batman in *The Dark Knight Rises*:

[image]

Let's not forget Matt Murdock's tag in *Daredevil* the movie:

[image]

Are there more cases of this in film and TV? Is it a just a trope, or just a coincidence?
**Or are any of these films paying homage to a predecessor?**

Comment: Sounds POB to me. I almost DVed you for not starting with a flaming crow. Then I began to wonder who did it first, which might be a better question. Also, are we talking about comic books or movies? Personally, I'd prefer screen adaptations only.

Comment: There's a site dedicated to compiling tropes. Social terms for it aren't terribly opinion based, we come to an agreement. I did mean super heroes. Film and Tv, yes. I can update. I tried tagging but there's not proper ones

Comment: Eric Draven did it first in The Crow.

Answer (score 5):

Definition of a trope by Merriam-Webster:

> Full Definition of trope. 1a : a word or expression used in a figurative sense : 
>   figure of speech **b : a common or overused theme or device**

The ["Flaming Emblem"](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/FlamingEmblem) entry under TV Tropes for when a character has their logo recreated using fire of some sort has 6 different entries under film including: your 3 examples, Eric Draven in "The Crow", a V made of fireworks for "V for Vendetta", and the Zorro 'Z' in "The Mask of Zorro".

Using Merriam-Webster's definition, I wouldn't really call it a trope **yet**, but I also wouldn't call it a coincidence. I would imagine multiple directors saw the idea and wanted to create something similar.

But then again it's listed in TV Tropes so take that as you will.

Comment: *Abashed the devil stood and felt how awful goodness is...* [{flink}](https://youtu.be/OB8uD8FaPXU?t=115)

Comment: I seem to recall some disdain for TDKR's use of this? Perhaps that starts the overused stage?